# Random de Enumerador

Tags: c++, random, enums

Não estou conseguindo fazer um random de enumerador.

```
enum Notas {A=10, B=22, C=31, D=44, E=56};
```

Tem essa solução, mas eu preciso dos valores dos enumeradores e aqui ele está retornando o resto do calculo.

```
enum Notas {A=10, B=22, C=31, D=44, E=56, ULTIMO};


int teste = static_cast<Notas>(rand() % ULTIMO);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema parece ser que os valores possíveis não são todos válidos.
No lugar de gerar direto o número randômico, você vai precisar de uma conversão.

Gere o número de acordo com a quantidade de elementos Notas. Se você tem 5 notas, de A a E, gere um número de 0 a 4 usando o:

```
enum Notas {A=10, B=22, C=31, D=44, E=56, ULTIMO};
#define NUMERO_DE_NOTAS 5

int teste = static_cast<Notas>(rand() % NUMERO_DE_NOTAS);
```

Depois disso, você usa o teste para entrar num switch e com cada valor retornar a nota correta. Se for 0, retorna A, se for 1, retorna B, etc...